# How can I allow Stripe to accept whole and decimal values on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decimal, stripe-payments, currency

Implemented Stripe on a a rails project. Stripe takes amount of '500' and sends 5.00 to their API by default. If I do amount.to_i*100 I can get '500' to stay 500, but then when amount = 5.67 getting 5.00 still.

How can I change the controller, view or field to allow for both correctly?

CONTROLLER CODE

`@amount = params[:amount].to_i*100`

VIEW CODE

`<input class="form-field two-decimals" name="amount" type="number" step="any" >`

Comment: `to_i` is for _integer_ conversion, truncating anything after a decimal place. Consider using `to_f`, which will read a floating-point number from the string.

Comment: Try using `(params[:amount].to_f*100).round` to get the integer value from a floating point string.  Note that I didn't use `.to_i`, as that may cause a math error, and opted to use `.round` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
@amount = sprintf("%.2f",(params[:amount])).delete '.'
```

Comment: This is what I ended up going with that worked. 

`@a = params[:amount].to_f*100
      @amount = @a.to_i`

Answer (score 0):

Stripe takes only integer, to get proper integer you can multiply amount to 100.

`(@amount * 100).to_i` => `44.53 * 100 = 4453.0.to_i` and converting to integer `4453`

```
def charge
    begin
        charged = Stripe::Charge.create(
          :amount   => (@amount * 100).to_i,
          :currency => "usd",
          :customer => @customer_id
        )
    rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError, Stripe::AuthenticationError, Stripe::APIConnectionError, Stripe::StripeError => e
        puts e.message
        return false
    end
    charged
end
```